# Tesseract not considering its variables

Tags: c++, tesseract

I am trying to make Tesseract recognize only numbers, I tried setting the variables below before and after Tesseract's initialization and just before the recognition but it never worked as it sometimes returned me letters. When I call GetStringVariable on the variables previously set, it returns me the correct value.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

```
tess->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_SINGLE_LINE);
tess->SetVariable("classify_bln_numeric_mode", "1");
tess->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

Comment: Well, e.g. you did not post necessary information like tesseract version. Some version did not have support for whitelist.

Comment: The version is 4.0.0

Comment: 4.0.0 is old version does not support whitelist/blacklist. You the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in python. It only outputs digits. But unfortunately it sometimes, depends on the font type, recognize I as 1 and Q as 0.

[sample.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYYgT.png)

```
tesseract sample.png stdout -l eng --oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist="0123456789"
2679
062171
21016
30363
2873
280929
3829
0584
8400
4523
0016
03016
4335
0205
20932
3760
02306
18204
6804
5866
```

Comment: This common problem in OCR - the easiest way in this case is to postprocess output with simple replacement table (l -> 1, O -> 0, S -> 5 etc.)

Comment: It is not as simple as that. If there is Q0 in the image and recognized as 00, then how could we know which one is derived from Q?

Comment: Original post and your code allows only 0123456789, so Q is not allowed, and your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: I am sorry. I should have said O for 0. In the example above OB3016R is recognized as 03016. There is now way we can tell which 0 in 03016 derives from O.

Comment: O is also out of restrictions ("0123456789"), so what is point of your comment? Your example is not corresponding to original post (_recognize only numbers_)

Comment: It corresponds to the post. Sometimes he got letters, while in my example, it only output digits. But unfortunately some digits are not true digits because they come from letters. But using substitution after getting digits is not gonna help because we can not tell the difference which digits come from letters.